# Simple Regex help needed

Tags: c#, regex

I need to create a regular expression to match a string that contains anything other than the specified characters. The characters are

a-z A-Z 0-9
+ - * / : . $ %
and a space

I'm not very familiar with regex so I'm unsure how to put it together and test it. I can find lots of cheat sheets but I don't know how to actually structure it as one whole pattern.

Comment: I recommend learning a bit about them.

Comment: Definitely will be doing so. Generally I just write ruthless for loops and check each character against a pre defined set. This is at least 100x faster!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a `^` in a <strike>capture group</strike> character class negates those characters in the class. So:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9+\-*/:.]
```

Some characters there are special chars in regex so they're escaped with `\`.

Comment: You don't need to escape `*` and `.` inside a character set.

Comment: Not really no Bart, but its good for a beginner to be aware of the importance of escaping.

Comment: @Russ, personally, I find it more important to get the point across that a character set is a small language of its own inside the regex language, with its own meta characters. By commenting that the "normal" meta chars have no "special powers" in them, I hope to accomplish this. I see patterns like `[a|b]` posted on a weekly basis here on SO where people think their regex will only match a `'a'` or `'b'`...

Comment: Ah I see, I was trying to use commas to seperate the differnt values. Also I wasn't using the ^.

Comment: (It's not a "capture group", it's a "character class".)

Answer (score 0):

```
~^[^a-z0-9\+\-\*\/\:\.\$\%\x20]*$~i
```

Starting with ^ and ending with $ to make sure that string contains only allowed characters.
Character group is starting with ^ for negation. \x20 stands for space, to much any whitespace use \x20. This RegExp is case insensitive (i modifier). You may test your regular expressions here http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Comment: Whats is the benefit of this version over the answer above?

Comment: Far too much escaping in your character set, IMO. It makes the pattern even harder to read/understand.

Comment: @James, this answer is different from mine in 2 ways. a) It assumes you only want to capture the beginning of the string b) it uses a more generic regex syntax (such as the `~i` part) which is not necessary in .NET as you specify the option flags when constructing the regex.